# is there any way to see all external environment variables in scons

Tags: scons

I am new to scons please help regarding this query
I want to see all **external environment variable values** that are present environment in scons build model
how to check **external environment values are set or not**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCons has three concepts of environment

1. External environment, mostly *not* used by SCons, and available as Python `os.environ`. If necessary, you can pull in values from here in your build scripts.
2. Construction environment, which is full of the things that are set up for SCons' own use. Once you've created one of these via, for example `env = Environment()`, its values can be looked at by doing `env.Dump()` which does a little formatting on it, or just by accessing `env` as a Python dictionary.
3. External environment, which is the values that will be passed as the environment to those processes, such as compilers, that are spawned by SCons. For a given construction environment `env`, those values are in `env['ENV']`